# How to convert Geographic Coordinate system to Projected coordinate system INDIA for HEC-RAS without ArcGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, hec-ras

The DEM data is downloaded from https://bhuvan-app1.nrsc.gov.in/ website.
I want to use it for HEC-RAS project but it has a geographical coordinate system, how can I convert it to projected one without ArcGIS?
P.S. I have QGIS!
.prj looks like:

```
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
        DATUM["D_WGS_1984",
              SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]
        ],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]
]
```

It is a 3600*3600 pixel DEM 1 Arc sec with the following parameters:

```
<Upper_left>cX = 74E, Y = 18N </Upper_left>
<Upper_right>X = 75E, Y = 18N </Upper_right>
<Lower_right>X = 75E, Y = 17N </Lower_right>
<Lower_left>cX = 74E, Y = 17N </Lower_left>
```

Comment: GDALWarp https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html or https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_gdaltools.html (look for warp (reproject)) from the QGIS interface. Which projected CRS do you need it to be in? If they are not compatible datums then you might need to use some more advanced options but if they are both based on WGS84 you should have no problem.

Comment: @MichaelStimson HEC-RAS needs ESRI PCS

Comment: There are thousands of Esri PCS to choose from. Between 72 and 78 E is UTM 43, could I suggest this would be something to try and see if it fits your other data? The Esri PCS code is EPSG:32643 https://www.spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84-utm-zone-43n/